# MySQL Init SQL files don't get mounted

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I have a MySQL database on Kubernetes. What I want to do is to run some SQL scripts to set up the database. I have tried to mount a host drectory on `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`, but when I try to see the contents of that directory it appears empty. My deployment file is the following:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: db
  labels:
    app: db
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: db
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mysql
          image: mysql:5.7.31
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
              name: initdb
            - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
              subPath: mysql
              name: db-data
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-secrets
                  key: ROOT_PASSWORD
      volumes:
        - name: db-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: db-data-disk-claim
        - name: initdb
          hostPath:
            path: /home/fer/web/db/sqlscripts
            type: Directory
```

Comment: Where are you storing the SQL script?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I solved it by creating a configMap and mounting it as a volume.

I'm leaving this here for future reference